# Issue with reading data from a socket and appending it to a stringbuilder

Tags: java, sockets, memory, stringbuilder

I have followed some tutorials to create a basic server that can handle multiple clients at once. It receives data correctly but it chews up more and more memory until it runs out of heap space. I believe it is because my loop is not recognising my end character and leaving the for loop.

Here is the code for the thread which receives the data:

```
 while (true){

            try {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                int character;
                StringBuilder process = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    while((character = isr.read()) != 13) {
                        process.append((char)character); //here is the issue - it just continues to append until it runs out of memory
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                parent.parent.writeToLog("Client " + Integer.toString(num) + " sent a message: " + process.toString());
                System.out.println(process);

                is = null;

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedOutputStream os;
            try {
                os = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                osw.write("Response from server at client socket " + Integer.toString(num) + " at " + (new java.util.Date()).toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I've put a comment into the code where it shows me the error on the stack trace. Here is the client, which is just the EchoClient from the Java tutorials:

```
  import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2405);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                    + "the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        out.println("Message to host: hello" + (char) 13);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println(Integer.toString((new Random()).nextInt()) + (char) 13);

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

You can see where I append the character 13 to the output and that is what is meant to end the loop but from my understanding this is not working. Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the following code:

```
                while((character = isr.read()) != 13) {
                    process.append((char)character); //here is the issue - it just continues to append until it runs out of memory
                }
```

Even when end of stream is reached `isr.read()` would return -1 and not 13. There's a possibility that you are never receiving input character that is 13 to exit out of the loop.

Comment: I never thought of it that way... thankyou very much and I will try this out. Just a thought: considering it is just returning -1 each time the loop runs, it will just keep appending this and that's what causes the memory leak?

Comment: That's right, like Cameron pointed out (char) -1 is unicode for 65535 character. Please accept the answer if you believe I helped you out

Comment: @cstream24: Yes, that's the most likely cause of the leak.

Comment: Now the memory leak is gone but my loop is constantly outputting blank messages from the client to my log. What do you think is the problem? I've only changed the 13 to a -1 and now it's just spamming me with blank messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the problem: `while((character = isr.read()) != 13)`

Why are you checking for 13? `InputStreamReader.read()` will return -1 if the end of the stream is reached.

My guess is that you're hitting the end of the stream and filling your StringBuilder with garbage. Note that `(char)-1` actually represents the unicode character 65535.

Comment: It was just what the example(s) used, actually. Thanks a lot